# One to Many Hibernate, adding many side with proxy object

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have two tables, say `A` and `B`. A is `One side`, and B is `many side`. Foreign key is in B only.

I need to know for a scenario where I need to persist `entity A`, along with adding relation to `entities in B`. (**B entities were already present**)

I tried it using `proxy object` using method `getReference()` of JPA. 
So I took proxy objects of B.

But when I tried doing `b.setA(a)` I saw hibernate loading the model despite `b` being only a reference of B.

**b is B object, a is A object.**

Can I do better?

Comment: you mean by loading the model excuting  query to get b?

Answer (score -1):

That is expected as getReference() gives you a proxy of the object and when this object is needed it executes the query and get it.

Comment: I listed my requirements in  the question. I want to know if there's a better way than using getReference().

Comment: Not sure what is the better you want , either way you need to load your object from the database, if you are looking for a performance you may want to look at a second layer cache.